# Footnote in Wyrd sisters - significant?

Tags: terry-pratchett

In Wyrd Sisters, by Terry Pratchett, there is a footnote that could be just a throwaway comment, or could refer to something. As it is Pratchett, I am inclined to think it is the latter.  Can anyone tell me what this passage refers to?

> "Sometime afterwards Magrat asked Hwel if he believed in long
>   engagements. The dwarf paused in the task of loading up the latty.
>   (25)"
>
> "(25) At least, of supervising the loading. Actual physical assistance
>   was a little difficult because he had, the day before, slipped on
>   something and broken his leg."

Now, I can't find any reference to anything Hwel could have slipped on. I can't find anything he has done that would cause anyone to attack him.

Why is it worthy of a footnote that he has broken his leg?

Comment: If you get a good answer, suggest an addition to the annotated Pratchett file: http://www.lspace.org/books/apf/wyrd-sisters.html

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes! The broken leg is significant. When the witches are participating in the play because Hwel has mistaken them for his own actors, Hwel gives them a pep talk that concludes with, "Break a leg." After he leaves, Nanny mutters, "Break your own leg."

> Hwel slapped Magrat on the bottom. "Good complexion you've got there, Wilph," he said encouragingly. "But for goodness' sake use a bit more padding, you're still the wrong shape. Fine warts there, Billem. I must say," he added, standing back, "you look as nasty a bunch of hags as a body might hope to clap eyes on. Well done. Shame about the wigs. Now run along. Curtain up on one minute. Break a leg."

...

> Nanny squinted sullenly after Hwel. "Break your own leg," she muttered.

Comment: Great! Thank you very much. My son said, "Marry, 'twas a note about the foot!". I have confiscated his figgin, which I think is a fitting punishment.

Comment: I think you should give him his figgin back, that was a pretty good pun